# Gulp-notify not showing pop-up notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, toast, gulp-notify

I'm using windows 8.1 and want to show error notifications with `gulp-notify`. Errors are printing in my console, but toasts just not appearing.

```
gulp.task ('sass', function() {
  return multipipe(
    gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass'),
    sass(),
    gulp.dest('app/css'),
  ).on('error', notify.onError(function (err) {
    return {
      title: 'style error(s)',
      message: err.message
    };
  }));
});
```

What I did try:

1. different code (even [examples](https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify/blob/master/examples/gulpfile.js))
2. update snoreToast manually (from [github](https://github.com/KDE/snoretoast))
3. add snoreToast to PATH variable and pass some text to the console
   `snoretoast -t "title"  -m "message"`. Toast was displayed and snoreToast appeared in the notification center in windows options. Seems, snoteToast can't get data.

What may be preventing the toast notification from popping up?